# Apache Log4j2 StrSubstitutor "default variable" does not work

Tags: java, log4j, string-substitution

I am trying to configure log4j2 logger. It uses [Apache StringSubstitutor](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html).

I want to set default root directory as "${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/${contextName}/logs/". And if property "userRootpath" has been set in logger.properties file, app should use it. I set it as "${bundle:logger:userRootpath}".

To implement this I'm trying to use ":-" **variable default value delimiter** which described [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html).
But it does not work if I set it as:

```
<Property name="defaultCatalinaRootpath">${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/${contextName}/logs/</Property>
<Property name="logDir">${bundle:logger:userRootpath:-${defaultCatalinaRootpath}}</Property>
```

It always just takes ${defaultCatalinaRootpath} and never consider ${bundle:logger:userRootpath} although *it has been set in logger.propetie*s.

If I set directory like this...

```
<Property name="logDir">${bundle:logger:userRootpath}</Property>
```

...or this...

```
<Property name="logDir">${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/${contextName}/logs/</Property>
```

...it works, so the case is not about corrupted properties initialization.

I tried to initialize properties in different ways inside ":-" structure, but nothing works for me.

***How can I achieve desired behavior?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debug I consider this is a bug, specified for bundle variables inside ":-" structure, I reported it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2913

If you have some ideas how to get around, please share, I would be grateful.